# Export Excel Table to Sharepoint List throwing publishing error?

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, excel, export, excel-services

I have a SP Foundation 2010 installation on windows 7.

I created a OOTB Contacts list in SharePoint and tried exporting an excel (Office 365) table with various fields to this list.
Note: The column headers do not necessarily match that of the OOTB contacts list's fields.

However I seem to get this error:

"Cannot connect to the server at this time. Your table cannot be published"

The suggestion at this link did not seem to make a difference either. 
http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2011/06/excel-cannot-connect-to-sharepoint-list.html

However, I am successfully able to import excel spreadsheets to SharePoint.

Any help is appreciated.